# jQuery Bootgrid rendering issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, jquery-bootgrid

I'm trying to use Bootgrid in a project of mine, and I want it to appear exactly as the example in http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples#data-api :

[image: Bootgrid Example]

However, when I wrote my own implementation, it rendered differently, as shown below:

[image]

Please notice the misaligned search icon, and the absence of borders in every button (search, refresh, items per page, column selector and pages).

This is the source HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type"
          content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
          content="ie=edge">

    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-zDnhMsjVZfS3hiP7oCBRmfjkQC4fzxVxFhBx8Hkz2aZX8gEvA/jsP3eXRCvzTofP"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bootgrid/1.3.1/jquery.bootgrid.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-S952WuaxC9XbI06xeWuSuSuvTewXEQQOU2OYBe7kdIs="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bootgrid/1.3.1/jquery.bootgrid.fa.min.js" 
            integrity="sha256-u/DZtNLWZSvkNdIL4PTQzEJUAFLzM758asxZnhd+5R4=" 
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS"
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
          integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" 
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bootgrid/1.3.1/jquery.bootgrid.min.css"
          integrity="sha256-i397iDijTcJqMf2j733J1b+WKakC2U8Y3k2eMScEugA="
          crossorigin="anonymous" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="responsiveTable m-5">
        <table id="grid-tarefas"
               class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped bootgrid-table"
               data-toggle="bootgrid"
               data-ajax="true"
               data-url="grid.php">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true">ID</th>
                    <th data-column-id="sender">Sender</th>
                    <th data-column-id="received" data-order="desc">Received</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(
            function (evt) {
                $("#grid-tarefas").bootgrid("reload");
            }
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Both were rendered in the same browser (Firefox 64.0.2 64-bit, Windows 10).

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong here... Are my JS and CSS references correct? Is there something missing?

Comment: Not sure if the library has been updated to work with Bootstrap 4.

Seems to work fine with Bootstrap 3.x.x

https://jsfiddle.net/pvcmbLd2/

Comment: Thank you! Sadly, since I had to use Bootstrap 4, I had to do it without that library...

Answer (score 1):

it's not your fault!
It's a little too late but maybe the answer can be useful for other people: I have fixed the issue. I have download the last bootgrid version (v1.3.1) and I have changed the following code in jquery.bootgrid.js

```
search: "<div class=\"{{css.search}}\"><div class=\"input-group\"><div class=\"input-group-prepend\"><span class=\"{{css.icon}} input-group-text {{css.iconSearch}}\"></span></div><input type=\"text\" class=\"{{css.searchField}}\" placeholder=\"{{lbl.search}}\" /></div></div>",
```

and I have add in jquery.bootgrid.css this code

```
ul.pagination li a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .5rem .75rem;
    margin-left: -1px;
    line-height: 1.25;
    color: #007bff;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
ul.pagination li.active a {
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #2196f3;
    border-color: #2196f3;
}
.btn-default {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color: #444;
    border-color: #ddd;
}
```

in my case now the library work very well with bootstrap 4!

Best regard, m.